# SS_ART_lib [I]: access to SS denied

Tags: android, permissions

From logfile on Samsung T815 (tablet) running Android 7.0:

```
    --------- beginning of main
    06-09 17:08:04.724 I/        (17393): SS_ART_lib [I]: permission is absent: /data/app/<my app>/base.apk
    06-09 17:08:04.724 I/        (17393): SS_ART_lib [I]: access to SS denied
    06-09 17:08:06.219 I/SELinux (17502): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=<my app>
```

what does SS_ART_lib stand for? What does it mean? What is SS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same in my logcat logs, but noticed a bit more context.  I think SS means Secure Storage.

This error shows up for me upon installing the app.

```
    08-07 08:55:35.053  2676  2842 I PackageManager: enforceEDMPermissionLI
    08-07 08:55:35.053  2676  2842 D SecureStorageService: apk path=/data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-1/base.apk
    08-07 08:55:35.053  2676  2842 D SecureStorageService: Called signDexFileInsideZip primaryAbi=arm
    08-07 08:55:35.053  2676  2842 D SecureStorageService: uid=10147
    08-07 08:55:35.053  2676  2842 D SecureStorageService: abi=32
    08-07 08:55:35.053  2676  2842 D SecureStorageService: type=dex
    08-07 08:55:35.133 17756 17756 I         : SS_ART_lib [I]: permission is absent: /data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-1/base.apk
    08-07 08:55:35.133 17756 17756 I         : SS_ART_lib [I]: access to SS denied
    08-07 08:55:35.133  2676  2842 E SecureStorageService: Process failed status=0x0200
    08-07 08:55:35.133  2676  2842 W PackageManager: Can't sign the dex file!
```

Comment: any idea, why are these logs are present. In my case, am not able to install wearable apk to watch. Apk is embedded in the mobile apk.